# Multi layer perceptron derivation

Tags: derivatives

I am stuck with the multi layer perceptron derivation (three layers, input-hidden-output).

In hidden layer: $$\mathbf{h} = f(W\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}) = f(\mathbf{p})$$
Output layer: $$\mathbf{y} = g(V\mathbf{h} + \mathbf{c}) = g(\mathbf{q})$$
where $f$ and $g$ are activation functions.

Loss function is $E$, $K$ is the number of categories in the output.

In the derivation, my textbook has this equation:
$$\frac{\partial E_n}{\partial p_j} = \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\partial E_n}{\partial q_k} \frac{\partial q_k}{\partial p_j} = \sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\partial E_n}{\partial q_k}\left( f^{'}(p_j) v_{kj} \right)$$

I could not understand why $$\frac{\partial q_k}{\partial p_j} = \left( f^{'}(p_j) v_{kj} \right)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $q = Vh+c$ and $h = f(p)$ : $$\frac{\partial q_k}{\partial p_j} =\frac{\partial q_k}{\partial h_j}\frac{\partial h_j}{\partial p_j} = v_{kj} f'(p_j)$$

The rest follows from the so-called [total-derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) 
$$v(t) = u(x(t),y(t)) \implies v'(t) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}[x(t),y(t)] x'(t)+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}[x(t),y(t)] y'(t)$$